# Is there a version of array_keys that works on partial matches?

Tags: php, arrays, match

I want to return all keys in a PHP array where the corresponding value contains a search element.

[`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will work if the value matches the search term exactly, but not if the search term occurs somewhere in the value but does not match it exactly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) can achieve what you want:

```
$myArray = ['knitting needle', 'haystack', 'needlepoint'];

$search = 'needle';
$keys = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        $myArray,
        function ($value) use ($search) {
            return (strpos($value, $search) !== false);
        }
    )
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/m6RKyg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom function:

```
function array_keys_partial(array $haystack, $needle) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (false !== stripos($value, $needle)) {
            array_push($keys,$key);
        }
    }
    if(empty($keys)){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return $keys;
    }
}
```

This will return the keys on partial matches, and is also case insensitive. If you want to make it case sensitive, change `stripos` to `strpos`.